# How can i design two column form layout without using tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, webforms

I am generating the html form by looping through the form variables like below

```
{% for field in form %}
 {{ LABEL }}{{ INPUT FIELD }}
```

The labels and fields go through loop . I can generate simple one column by

```
 {% for field in form %}
     <div>{{ LABEL }}</div><div>{{ INPUT FIELD }}</div>
```

But i have 20 fields so i want to have 2 column layout with text on upper line and field below it. But i don't know how i can do in loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of wrapping each item in a `div`, wrap the items you want to keep together:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div>{{ LABEL }}{{ INPUT FIELD }}</div>
```

Then in your CSS do something like this:

```
form { width: 800px; /* or whatever */ }
form > div { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
label, input { display: block; }
```

You may need to adjust the widths to account for padding, margins etc.  The form fields will flow right to left and down the page in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Our should style your label and input fields with CSS. There is the standard instruction by the "Gurus" of A List apart: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

However, this will break with forms that have labels that are longer than one line.

Also popular is wrapping labels and elements in definition lists (instead of using `div` elements). You can read here on how to style such a form: http://aspnetresources.com/blog/styling_definition_lists
If such HTML is still semantic is highly debated however, so beware of HTML standard nerds.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "float" property of css to arrange controls in two columns...

Check this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp